# SPOILER: CS50: PSET6, DNA. How do I count in the 1s and 2s to solve small.csv?

Tags: cs50

I am having a problem with my code.

I have to insert this part of my code:

```
lresults = [i for i in lresults if i != '1' and i != '2']
```

so that I can get the correct match for the large.csv. The above line removes all the 1s and 2s.

If I do not put this line of code in, I get these kinds of answers:

```
['1', '46', '1', '1', '1', '49', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '48', '1', '1', '1', '1', '29', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '15', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '5', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '28', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '40', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1']
```

However, I would need 1 and 2 to solve the part for small.csv.

I hope the above is easy to understand, and I will appreciate any help on this.

Thank you!

The full code is as below.

```
import csv
import os
import re
from sys import argv


while True:
    # for the missing command line argument
    if len(argv) < 2:
        print("Usage: python dna.py data.csv sequence.txt")
    else:
        num_of_rows = 0
        # Open the CSV file aka the databases file
        with open(argv[1]) as csvfile:
            reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)

            data = []
            for row in reader:
                key_list = list(row.keys())
                val_list = list(row.values())
                data.append(val_list)
                num_of_rows += 1

        # Open the sequences file, and get the results as a string, and split the string into 4 characters each,
        # with each of the attribute as a dictionary key
        with open(argv[2]) as csvfile:
            seq_reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
            for row in seq_reader:
                text_inside_seq_reader = "".join(row)

        # The below method is to find the max number of repeats inside the sequence
        lresults = []
        for seq in key_list[1:]:
            pattern = re.compile(r'({})+'.format(seq))
            matches = pattern.finditer(text_inside_seq_reader)
            for match in matches:
                value = match.end() - match.start()
                num_of_repeats = value / len(seq)
                lresults.append(str(round(num_of_repeats)))

        lresults = [i for i in lresults if i != '1' and i != '2']

        print(lresults)

        # This below code is to ensure that the database file gives the name with the DNA values in a row
        n = 0
        answer = ""
        while n < num_of_rows:
            if data[n][1:] == lresults:
                answer = data[n][0]
                print(answer)
                n += 1
            else:
                n += 1

        if answer == "":
            print("No match")
        break
    break
```

Comment: Perhaps you will find the [python built-in max function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) useful in solving this problem.

Comment: Hey thanks! I'll go give it a try.